# C++ program crashes after calling destructor containing delete operator

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

This program executes up to the calling of destructor but then crashes with the error:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED...CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Although many similar threads asks to use vectors, I don't yet know how to use vectors. Also I think I should be using **delete[ ]** instead of **delete**. But the strange thing is that when I use **delete[ ]**, the program crashes one step earlier (i.e before displaying the matrices) than when I'm not using **delete[ ]**.

How do I get rid of this error? Is this somehow linked to the use of for loops?

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
  int n_row, n_col;

  public:

  Matrix(int a = 0, int b = 0)
  {
     n_row = a;
     n_col = b;
  }

  int *m = new int[n_col*n_row];

  ~Matrix()
  {
     cout << "\t deallocating memory\t\n\n";
     delete m;                //ERROR??
  }
 void input_M(int a[], int r, int c);

 void display_M(int a[], int r, int c);

};

void Matrix::input_M(int a[], int r, int c)
{
  cout << "\nEnter elements row-wise\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
          cin >> a[i*j + j];
}

void Matrix::display_M(int a[], int r, int c)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
   {
       cout << "\n\n\n";
       for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
         cout << a[i*j + j] << "\t";
   }
 }


int main()
{
   cout << "  C++ Program to display MATRIX ";

   int r1, r2, c1, c2;

   cout << "\n\n Enter the number of Rows for the First Matrix\t\t:\t";
   cin >> r1;

   cout << "\n\n Enter the number of Columns for the First Matrix\t:\t";
   cin >> c1;

   cout << "\n\n Enter the number of Rows for the Second Matrix\t\t:\t";
   cin >> r2;

   cout << "\n\n Enter the number of Columns for the Second Matrix\t:\t";
   cin >> c2;

   Matrix s1(r1, c1), s2(r2, c2);

   cout << "\nEnter elements for the first Matrix\n";

   s1.input_M(s1.m, r1, c1);       //ALIAS??

   cout << "\nEnter elements for the second Matrix\n";

   s2.input_M(s2.m, r2, c2);
   system("cls");

   cout << "\t\tMatrix 1\n\n";
   s1.display_M(s1.m, r1, c1);

   cout << "\n\n\n\n\t\tMatrix 2\n\n";
   s2.display_M(s2.m, r2, c2);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: all you need to know about vectors to start working with them is: `std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>(size,init_value); v.push_back(element);`

Comment: Your code does not follow the rule of three. Look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete an array, you have to do use brackets `delete[] m;`

For example:

```
int *m = new int[n_col*n_row];
delete[] m;

int *m = new int; // single element
delete m;
```

As for your other problem, the reason why your program was crashing is because

```
    Matrix(int a = 0, int b = 0)
    { 
        n_row = a;
        n_col = b;
     }

     // this line is executed before you set n_row and n_col
     int *m = new int[n_col*n_row];
```

The fix: make sure n_row, and m_col are set before you use them to create the dynamic array

```
Matrix(int a = 0, int b = 0) : n_row(a), n_col(b), m(new int[a*b]) {    }
or
Matrix(int a = 0, int b = 0)
{
    n_row = a;
    n_col = b;
    m = new int[a*b];
}
```

Comment: As I said, I too though that to be the logical way, but the program is crashing earlier than when not using delete[ ] ... why is that happening?

Comment: I've explained why your program is crashing.

Comment: oo...never mind...reloading the page showed your complete answer. Earlier only 1st para was being shown.

Answer (score 1):

Yu should put your matrix allocation into constructor:

```
  Matrix(int a = 0, int b = 0)
  {
     n_row = a;
     n_col = b;
     m = new int[n_col*n_row];
  }
```

second thing, as you say - you should use `delete[]`

Comment: Third thing, just use a vector and don't mess around with raw pointers.

Comment: @SvenMarnach make it an answer

Comment: The OP actually mentions vectors in the question, and there's already a comment on the question.